# How to Download New Tex Maker Packages?

Tags: packages, texmaker

I am currently using Tex Maker on macOS. I have been trying to download a new package, but no luck doing. I downloaded the package I wanted, mathtime, but I don't know where to move it to in the directory and how to use it. Could someone please help?

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using; e.g., MacTeX (TeX Live)? TeXmaker is a front tend to a TeX distribution.

Comment: I am using MiK Tex.

Comment: I believe there is a program called the MikTeX Console that is used to install new packages.